# How do I find the alignment of a struct in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to query for the alignment of a (blittable) struct in C#?

```cs
public static int AlignmentOf<T>() where T : unmanaged
{
    // what do
}
```

If there is no built-in way, is it just a matter of traversing the fields via reflection and finding the widest primitive?

Comment: What do you expect this to return for `struct S { short A; int B; }`?

Comment: @MichaelLiu I assume you'd want 4 for that one.

Comment: _the default alignment of the type is the size of its largest element, which is greater than or equal to all other field lengths_ - and much more info at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-4-fields-layout/

Comment: @stuartd Isn't the alignment technically the _alignment_ of the largest element? (The alignment is just the size if it's a primitive.) If I have another struct in the middle whose alignment is 2, wouldn't the overall alignment be 4 (assuming there is an int nearby)?

Comment: I'm curious why you are interested in this. When I was a C (and to a lesser extent, when I worked in C++) I cared about this. I haven't really cared at all in the last 20 years. Also realize that unless you add a `[StructLayout]` attribute, the language can rearrange your struct. Also realize that the results of this can change depending on machine architecture; most chips are fussing about alignment than are Intel chips.

Comment: @Flydog57 Building an arena allocator for C# using spans. The context is game dev, but I may use the arena other places as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched the .NET documentation, looking particularly at the [Marshal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal) and [Unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe) classes, but I didn't find this functionality.

Instead of using Reflection, *maybe* something like this would work? Basically, see how .NET aligns the struct `T` within another struct.

```
internal struct AlignmentHelper<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    public byte Padding;
    public T Target;
}

public static int AlignmentOf<T>() where T : unmanaged
{
    return (int)Marshal.OffsetOf<AlignmentHelper<T>>(nameof(AlignmentHelper<T>.Target));
}
```

For example:

```
struct Example1
{
    public byte A;
    public byte B;
    public int C;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
struct Example2
{
    public byte A;
    public byte B;
    public int C;
}

Console.WriteLine(AlignmentOf<Example1>()); // 4
Console.WriteLine(AlignmentOf<Example2>()); // 2
```

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised at the lack of core functionality to do this for me. But yeah, I like this approach. Much cleaner than attempting to walk the fields manually. Clever way to force the answer out of the language/runtime itself.